# How to check a document includes a list of fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection that has documents that include both required and non-required data. I know how to create a query using the $exists operator to check if a field exists, however I do not want to define required field within the query, as the list is both long and subject to change (and is define elsewhere).

The following is great for checking a known field:

```
db.collectionofstuff.find({fieldIneed:{$exists:False}})
```

However I want something that function like this:

Using this Config file:

```
datadescriptorjson = {"thing1": {"count": 2,"range": 3},"thing2":{"pace": 12.5, "consistency": "angry"}}
```

create a query find/aggregation that looks something like this:

```
db.collectionofstuff.find({<list of fields from datadescriptorjson>:{$exists:Falze}})
```

I am not aware of anyway to do it directly with either the aggregation framework or using a simple find.

Comment: In your example "Config file", what are the required fields you're trying to check for?  All of the fields that are exist in the JSON?

Comment: Yes, all fields in the JSON config file are required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function, you will have to test each field manually. You can of course loop over your config data and recreate a query out of this. However, this should be something you do in your application.